# return duplicates in a list

Tags: python, list, count

This function takes an integer list (which your function must not modify) of unsorted values and returns a sorted list of all the duplicates in that first list. For example, `duplicates([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 5, 3])` would return `[3, 5]`. If there are no duplicates, return an empty list.

Following is my current code, which doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

```
def FindDuplicates(in_list):  
    unique = set(in_list)  
    for each in unique:  
        count = in_list.count(each)  
        if count > 1:  
            print count  
            return True  
    print []  
    return False
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this without a Counter/dict, you can modify your current code to save the duplicate values in a new list, like below:

```
def FindDuplicates(in_list):  
    duplicates = []
    unique = set(in_list)
    for each in unique:
        count = in_list.count(each)
        if count > 1:
            duplicates.append(each)
    print duplicates
```

which will output:

```
>>> FindDuplicates(lst)
[3, 5]
```

If you need sorted results, use a `sorted(duplicates)` call at the end to get results sorted by their values.

---

You can also solve this (i.e. finding duplicates in a list) using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a list comprehension, as below:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 5, 3]
>>> def duplicates(list_of_numbers):
...    counter = Counter(list_of_numbers)
...    return [y for y in counter if counter[y] > 1]
... 
>>> duplicates(lst)
[3, 5]
```

The above solution assumes the elements of the list are hashable.

Comment: Are you sure this answers the OPs question? Cause as of right now there isnt one...

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I used counter before and my teacher said that I'm not allowed to do it. is there any way to do it without counter?

Comment: I think you also need a call to `sorted` because counters are arbitrary-order?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen No, order won't be necessarily restored if `sorted` is used. The dicts do not maintain order of keys, and there is no guarantee original list is sorted.

Comment: @Aleish Check edits.., I have edited your current code. This is an unoptimal solution O(N^2), but am not sure if you are allowed to use `dict`s either.

Comment: @heinst I'm hoping it does answer the question now :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly faster, at O(nlogn) worst-case

```
def FindDuplicates(in_list):  
    unique = set()
    duplicates = set()
    for i in in_list:
        if i in unique: #hey, I've seen you before
            duplicates.add(i)
        else:
            unique.add(i)
    return sorted(duplicates) 
    #It's this call to sorted that makes it O(nlogn)
    #without it, it'd be O(n)
```

Also the "Man, you can't stop me from using a counter!" variant. Also O(nlogn).

```
def FindDuplicates(in_list):
    d = {}
    for i in in_list:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return sorted(i for i,j in d.items() if j > 1)
   #python2 use d.iteritems() not d.items()
```

(I suppose

```
if i not in d:
    d[i] = 1
else:
    d[i] += 1
```

makes more sense to most people, and it'd work too.)

Comment: If you remove the sorted calls, both the solutions become O(n). Is sorted really needed here?

Comment: From the question: "returns a sorted list of all the duplicates in that first list" So, yes.

Comment: Ah, missed that completely while reading the question. Also understand your comment on my answer now. +1.